# jQuery & Perl/CGI: add CGI content in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, perl, cgi

I would like to add stuff to body when I click on a checkbox, it's ok, I found how to do.
My problem is that I just can add pure HTML, but I want to add Perl/CGI.
I explain:

```
$(function() {
    $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
        var nom = $(this).attr("value");
        if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $('body').append($("<div id="+nom+">Switch "+nom+"</div>"));
        } 
        else {
            $("#" + nom).remove();
        }
    });
```

Insetad of `"<div id="+nom+">Switch "+nom+"</div>"` can I append `SwitchGUI->new("switch-rdc-7", 24, 2)` ?
SwitchGUI is a perl module I've written, it execute a perl file, draw a switch, fill informations for each interface...
 Here is [SwitchGUI.pm](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:1a00)

Comment: Ew, french code. Hey everyone out there writing non-english code: Think about those who might have an easier time reading your code in the future when its variable names don't use $random_language. (fyi, I'm German and also rant about people who use German in their code)

Comment: Too dificult for you to read 3 letter in french ? It's just functions or variables names, it's not the main thing in the code. First stupid answer I read on this website. After re-reading, french words : Erreur (error in english, not too difficult TeethMaster ?), afficher (=display), nom (=name).

Comment: I didn't say it's a problem in your code and neither was it an answer but just a comment. Just a general rant about non-english code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. jQuery runs in the user's browser, your perl code runs on your server; there's no way for jQuery to inject perl code into the current page and have it run. If you need to run server-side code which has an effect on what the browser is displaying, use AJAX.

Comment: Ok, I see, that's what i tought. Have you got some links/tips to help me to implement it ?

Comment: Not to mention an out of print book from 1997.

Comment: @eouti: now that you know you need to use AJAX, type "jquery ajax" into google and follow some of the links like this one: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

It's even easier than you probably imagine. From the look of that jQuery, that's just basically an equivalent of document.write on document load. What you need is a CGI url to send back just the html for that division.

```
$.get("get_gui_div.cgi?param=value", function( data ) {
    $( "#" + nameOfMyDiv ).html( data );
  });
```

Depending on the complexity of your CGI, it might just be:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -wT
use strict;
use warnings;
use SwitchGUI;

# ... deal with params ...

print SwitchGUI->new( "switch-rdc-7", 24, 2 );
```

But you have to keep in mind that the two layers *cannot* communicate between each other outside of HTTP requests and responses. Whatever you put in the code for the main document will run *once* to send the document. Any dynamic update will require separate request, and you'll likely have to provide parameters so the Perl knows what type of text to send back, and then it will send back an HTML *fragment* to be sent down to the Ajax/jQuery layer (It could also send JSON as well). So you pretty much have to have your connection points straight.

- New JavaScript *can* be sent with the HTML fragment
- You can have your Perl layer "paste" values into it.
- You can rig something to run server-provided JavaScript upon receipt--though that is not straightforward

In short, you send or post *values* to the Perl and return *text* that the browser can evaluate, whether HTML, JSON, XML, or even JavaScript.